# Sort NSMenuItems alphabetically, and by whether they have submenus or not?

Tags: objective-c

It seems like this might be a common thing to do but the docs and google are failing me. I would like all the items in an NSMenu to be sorted alphabetically. I would also like all items that have sub-menus to be sorted first. I'm writing custom code using an NSComparator right now, but I figured I'd ask and see if this is built-in at all? Path Finder does it. I think Finder might do it, too.

Answer (score 4):

I've made the following code, so I'm guessing I've answered my own question:

```
-(void)sortMenu:(NSMenu*)menu
{
    // [CH] Get an array of all menu items.
    NSArray* items = [menu itemArray];
    [menu removeAllItems];
    // [CH] Sort the array
    NSSortDescriptor* alphaDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor* submenuDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"hasSubmenu" ascending:NO];
    items = [items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:submenuDescriptor,alphaDescriptor, nil]];
    // [CH] ok, now set it back.
    for(NSMenuItem* item in items){
        [menu addItem:item];
        /**
         * [CH] The following code fixes NSPopUpButton's confusion that occurs when
         * we sort this list. NSPopUpButton listens to the NSMenu's add notifications
         * and hides the first item. Sorting this blows it up.
        **/
        if(item.isHidden){
            item.hidden = false;
        }
        // [CH] While we're looping, if there's a submenu, go ahead and sort that, too.
        if(item.hasSubmenu){
            [self sortMenu:item.submenu];
        }
    }
}
```